# Add Data to DataRepeater Control in winform

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, datarepeater

Visual Studio 2008 service pack 1  comes with Visual Basic Powerpack and has DataRepeatr control.

i want to know that how I can add data in this control. i have in memory data. the examples i found on net are about binding DataSet to DataRepeater by fetching data from database. i want to bind in memory data. how to do this.

Comment: @Mohsan : What you mean by in memory data?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted _how_ you solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding a new DataSet from Add New Item.
Create new DataTable in DataSet.

Add items from DataTable to DataRepeater using DataSource Explorer.

fill the data table from code.. thats the whole process i did.